# Umbraco 7 : How to add comments to documents you can't edit

Tags: umbraco7

Sorry for multiple postings, but I am going round in circles and not even sure there is a solution even by tinkering with the API.

In a nutshell, the requirement is (on an intranet) news articles

some of which any user (not member) can edit,

some of which only admins (or some other way of protecting them for selected users) can edit.

The requirement is that anyone can post a comment against any article (even if they can't edit that particular article). (ie similar to a blog),

Viewing articles in the front end should list their comments underneath.

They don't necessarily need to be able to see the protected articles in the CMS as I am using Frontend Editing package so they can view them in the front end and then use the 'create' button to create child documents - ie the comments. Although this doesn't work if they don't have access to edit the article - and thus my problem.

How could this be achieved in Umbraco 7?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would implement it in the Frontend Editing stuff in place, but maybe you could make your own "create comment" button somewhere, or override the content creation flow for comments? If so, I'm thinking you could try ContentService.CreateContent(...) or .CreateContentWithIdentity(...) with a specific user Id. Create a "Comment User" with appropriate permissions and use that users Id to create the content. Maybe :-s
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/ContentService